# VBA: Delete duplicate entries (Row) in column S based on the lowest price in column Q

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to vba and have got help here earlier with some issues I had with vba macros, now I need help again.

I have an excel file with tons of data and I have huge amounts of duplicate EAN numbers in column S, I want to delete all duplicate EANs (the entire rows with the duplicates) but keep the one with lowest price (column Q), so I want to compare duplicate EANs from column S and delete all duplicates based on the lowest prices in column Q and keep the cheapest one. It's alot of data, more than 10000 rows, so do this manually by a formel is not the best way, takes alot of time to delete this rows manually.

example below (the first is price and second should be an ean):

1. 104,93 - 000000001
2. 104.06 - 000000001
3. 104.94 - 000000001

in this case I want to delete first and third row and keep the second, anyone knows how the macro should look like, i use Excel 2010 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you.

I assume you have a Header row. If not, change iHeaderRowIndex to 0 .

The first part creates a dictionary object, collects all the unique EAN numbers, and for each EAN it assigns a very high price (10 million)

Then it rescans the list, this time does a "MIN" logic to determine the lowest price per EAN.

Another rescan, this time it puts a MIN mark in a free column next to each min EAN (you should choose a name of a free and empty column -  I put in "W" but you can change that)

Last, it rescans the list, in reverse order, to delete all the lines that do not have the MIN mark.  Also, at the end, it deletes the column with the MIN marks.

```
Public Sub DoDelete()
Dim oWS As Worksheet
Dim d As Object, k As Object
Dim a As Range
Dim b As Range
Dim sColumnForMarking As String
Dim iHeaderRowIndex As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim iRowsCount As Integer
Dim v As Double


Set oWS = ActiveSheet
Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

' ----> Put here ZERO if you do not have a header row !!!
iHeaderRowIndex = 1
' ----> Change this to what ever you like. This will be used to mark the minimum value.
sColumnForMarking = "W"

' Selecting the column "S"
Set a = _
oWS.Range(oWS.Cells(1 + iHeaderRowIndex, "S"), _
          oWS.Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, "S"))

' putting a high number, one that is beyond the max value in column Q
' ----> Change it if it is too low !!!!
For Each b In a
    d(b.Text) = 9999999   ' very high number, A max++ to all the prices
Next

For Each b In a
    v = CDbl(oWS.Cells(b.Row, "Q").Value)

    If v < CDbl(d(b.Text)) Then
        d(b.Text) = v
    End If
Next

For Each b In a
    v = CDbl(oWS.Cells(b.Row, "Q").Value)

    If v = CDbl(d(b.Text)) Then
        oWS.Cells(b.Row, sColumnForMarking).Value = "MIN"
    End If
Next


' This part deletes the lines that are not marked as "MIN".

iRowsCount = oWS.UsedRange.Rows.Count

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For i = iRowsCount To iHeaderRowIndex + 1 Step -1
    If oWS.Cells(i, sColumnForMarking).Text <> "MIN" Then
        oWS.Rows(i).Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
    End If
Next

' clean up- deletes the mark column
oWS.Columns(sColumnForMarking).EntireColumn.Delete

Application.ScreenUpdating = True    
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you so much, El Scripto, it worked exactly what it should do and its only took 5 seconds instead of a Whole day to delete them manually :)

Comment: Great stuff !  Thank you for letting me know that it has helped you.